# Discord bot on python dont send message

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I made a leaderboard for money, there are no errors in the console, but the bot does not give anything after the .lb or .lbs command.

Code:

````
import asyncio
import string
import aiofiles
import discord
import json
import os
import logging
from PIL import Image
from discord.utils import get
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ext.commands import has_permissions
from discord.ext.commands import MissingPermissions
from discord.ext.commands import Bot
from discord.ext.commands import cooldown
from discord.ext.commands import BucketType
import random

os.chdir("/home/kali/Desktop/DISCORD_BOT/")

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True
intents.message_content = True
client = discord.Client(intents=intents)

discord.utils.setup_logging()
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = ".", intents=intents)
client.remove_command('help')

@client.command()
async def bal(ctx):
    await open_account(ctx.author)
    user = ctx.author
    users = await get_bank_data()

    wallet_amt = users[str(user.id)]["wallet"]
    bank_amt = users[str(user.id)]["bank"]
    pfp = ctx.author.display_avatar
    em = discord.Embed(title = f" {ctx.author.name} balance", color = discord.Color.green())
    em.add_field(name = "Wallet ", value = f'```{wallet_amt}```')
    em.add_field(name = "Bank ", value = f'```{bank_amt}```') 
    em.set_thumbnail(url=f'{pfp}')
    await ctx.send(embed = em)

async def open_account(user):

    users = await get_bank_data()

    if str(user.id) in users:
        return False
    else:
        users[str(user.id)] = {}
        users[str(user.id)]["wallet"] = 0
        users[str(user.id)]["bank"] = 0

    with open ("mainbank.json", "w") as f:
        json.dump(users,f)
    return True

async def get_bank_data():
    with open("mainbank.json","r") as f:
        users = json.load(f)

    return users

async def update_bank(user, change = 0, mode = "wallet"):
    users = await get_bank_data()

    users[str(user.id)][mode] +=change

    with open ("mainbank.json", "w") as f:
        json.dump(users,f)
        
    balance = [users[str(user.id)]["wallet"],users[str(user.id)]["bank"]] 
    return balance

@client.command(aliases = ["lb"])
async def lbs(ctx,x = 3):
    with open('mainbank.json', 'r') as f:
        users = await get_bank_data()

    leader_board = {}
    total = []

    for user in users:
        name = int(user)
        total_amount = users[user]["wallet"] + users[user]["bank"]
        leader_board[total_amt] = name
        total.append(total_amt)

    total = sorted(total, reverse=True)

    em = discord.Embed(title=f"Top {x} Richest People", description="This is decided on the basis of raw money in the bank and wallet", color = discord.color.random())
    
    index = 1
    for amt in total:
        id_ = leader_board[amt]
        member = client.fetch_user(id_)
        name = member.name
        em.add_field(name=f"{index}. {name}", value=f"{amt}")
        if index == x:
            break
        else:
            index += 1
    await ctx.send(embed=em)
````

Not full code, cuz is the main code, other commands is warn, deposite, slots and etc. I don`t think u need this commands.
I try import logging, but nothing happened anyway, no error, no message when I write .lb or .lb 1

Comment: Have you enabled the `message_content` intent?

Comment: @Hazzu if you mean intent.message_content = True , yes i enable

Comment: I believe that an error is occurring, but it is not being shown because you did not activate the logs. Use the `discord.utils.setup_logging()` function in the `main` file to use a default logging setup.

Comment: I put `discord.utils.setup_logging()` in `main` code and nothing happened, I new in discord.py, mb need some put in `() `?

Comment: You will need to send your complete code so that we can evaluate it better.

Comment: I update post, check main code

Comment: Instantiating a `Client` does nothing, since you then rebind the same variable to a `Bot` instance. Also welcome to Stack Overflow! Would you mind taking a look at how to prepare a [MRE]? Try and make the shortest possible code that still runs on its own, is clear to read, and demonstrated the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I found error, thank you so much Hazzu, I use `amount` in id_, i replace `amount` to `amt` and code was work. If some need worked code:

```
async def lbs(ctx,x = 3):
    with open('mainbank.json', 'r') as f:
        users = await get_bank_data()

    leader_board = {}
    total = []
    for user in users:
        name = int(user)
        total_amount = users[user]["wallet"] + users[user]["bank"]
        leader_board[total_amount] = name
        total.append(total_amount)
    total = sorted(total, reverse=True)
    print("JOINED")
    em = discord.Embed(title=f"Top {x} Richest People", description="This is decided on the basis of raw money in the bank and wallet", color = discord.Color.random())
    
    index = 1
    for amt in total:
        id_ = leader_board[amt]
        member = client.get_user(id_)
        name = member.name
        em.add_field(name=f"{index}. {name}", value=f"{amt}")
        if index == x:
            break
        else:
            index += 1
    await ctx.send(embed=em)
```

Answer (score -1):

I have identified some problems in your code:

- For some unknown reason you are creating a `discord.Client` instance and then replacing it with `commands.Bot` instance. Know that `Bot` is a subclass of `Client` dedicated to the development of bots, being the best choice for your case;
- You are not running your bot anywhere in your code. In order for it to start responding to commands, you need to start the Discord connection. To run your bot, add this at the end of your code:

```py
async def main():
    async with client:
        await client.start(TOKEN)

asyncio.run(main())
```

- It is strongly recommended that you use the [on_ready](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Client.event) event to print some informational message when the bot is ready. This way you will be sure that your bot is running:

```py
@client.event
async def on_ready():
   print(">>> BOT ONLINE <<<")
```

Comment: i have bot.run('token') and `@client.event async def on_ready(): print(client.user.name + " is ready.")`. My bad i dont put in code this

Comment: and i dont have cogs or databases

Comment: Are you sure you're sending messages in a channel where your bot can see and respond?

Comment: @howa One thing you didn't explicitly say in your question... are the non-aliased command names working? For instance, `.balance`?

Comment: yes, I check in my main server and empty server and dm, nothing

Comment: @CrazyChucky I have `.bal` its yourself balance and `.bala @member` its member balance.

Comment: everything works except the command `.lb`

Comment: @howa `member = client.fetch_user(id_)` This line is incorrect. Use `client.get_user(id_)`, except if you don't have `intent.members` and want to make an API call using `await client.fetch_user`

Comment: @Hazzu anyway not working :(

Comment: To help you find the problem, put a `print("JOINED")` at the beginning of the command. This way you will know if the command is being triggered.

Comment: i put it everywhere and after `leader_board[total_amt] = name` print not working

Comment: Obviously there will be an undeclared variable error. You perhaps meant `total_amount`.
But for some reason your bot is not printing the errors in the terminal. Did you happen to override the `on_error` or `on_command_error` events?

Comment: You should add the `discord.utils.setup_logging()` line immediately before running the bot.